# Laravel Collection - Return value only, don't want key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have a set of Laravel collection, but I only need the values, see the sample collection below, I only need `A1`, `1.00`, and I don't need `header 1`, `header 2`...

Below is the collection.

```
{
    header 1: "A1",
    header 2: "1.00",
    header 3: "2020-04-15",
    header 4: "D1 %",
    header 5: "1",
    header 6: "F1",
    header 7: "G1",
    header 8: "H1",
    header 9: "I1",
    header 10: "J1",
    header 11: "K1",
    header 12: "L1",
    header 13: "M1"
},{
    header 1: "A2",
    header 2: "2.00",
    header 3: "2020-04-16",
    header 4: "D2",
    header 5: "2",
    header 6: "F2",
    header 7: "G2",
    header 8: "H2",
    header 9: "I2",
    header 10: "J2",
    header 11: "K2",
    header 12: "L2",
    header 13: "M2"
},
```

Below is the code:

```
    $collect = $collection->map(function ($rows) {
        return collect($rows)->map(function ($item, $key) {
            return $item;
        });
    });
    return $collect->values()->all();
```

However, I always get the full set of collections including `header 1`, `header 2`.

Tried code below,

```
$collect = $collection->map(function ($rows) {
        return collect($rows)->map(function ($item) {
            return collect($item)->values();
        });
    });

    return $collect->values()->all();
```

but the output is as below,

```
{
header 1: [
"A1"
],
header 2: [
"1.00"
],
header 3: [
"2020-04-15"
],
header 4: [
"D1 %"
],
header 5: [
"1"
],
header 6: [
"F1"
],
header 7: [
"G1"
],
header 8: [
"H1"
],
header 9: [
"I1"
],
header 10: [
"J1"
],
header 11: [
"K1"
],
header 12: [
"L1"
],
header 13: [
"M1"
]
},
```

Comment: Since it looks like the headers are in the second level then something like `$collect->map(function ($inner) { return collect($inner)->values(); })` might work

Comment: @apokryfos thank you but it's not what i want. see my updates.

Comment: Run that directly on `$collection` not on the subfunction

Comment: @apokryfos yup you are right. i removed the ($rows) that line and now it works! your comment helped! thank you

Comment: @apokryfos sorry would like to ask, is that possible if i'd like to get "header 1", "header 2"? :)

Comment: Normally you'd do `$collections->first()->keys()` but need a check first in case `$collections` is empty

Comment: @apokryfos but keys() will return me 0,1,2,3 instead of "header 1", "header 2"

Comment: You should do this before you strip the headers out. Take the keys of the first row and put them somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have a follwing array

```
$arrayTbs = [
    [
        'header 1' => "A1",
        'header 2' => "1.00",
        'header 3' => "2020-04-15",
        'header 4' => "D1 %",
        'header 5' => "1",
        'header 6' => "F1",
        'header 7' => "G1",
        'header 8' => "H1",
        'header 9' => "I1",
        'header 10' => "J1",
        'header 11' => "K1",
        'header 12' => "L1",
        'header 13' => "M1"
    ],[
        'header 1' => "A2",
        'header 2' => "2.00",
        'header 3' => "2020-04-16",
        'header 4' => "D2",
        'header 5' => "2",
        'header 6' => "F2",
        'header 7' => "G2",
        'header 8' => "H2",
        'header 9' => "I2",
        'header 10' => "J2",
        'header 11' => "K2",
        'header 12' => "L2",
        'header 13' => "M2"
    ]
];
```

If you need all the values

```
$collectionOne = collect($arrayTbs)
        ->map(function($value,$key){
          return collect($value)->values();
        });
```

if you need all those values on single array

```
$collectiontwo = collect($arrayTbs)
        ->map(function($value,$key){
          return collect($value)->values();
        })->collapse();
```

If you need all the keys

```
$collectionThree = collect($arrayTbs)
        ->map(function($value,$key){
          return collect($value)->keys();
        });
```

if you need all those keys on single array

```
$collectionThree = collect($arrayTbs)
        ->map(function($value,$key){
          return collect($value)->keys();
        })->collapse();
```

[Live Demo](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/11958c0b-9ed2-4e92-b86e-35c11fada403)

Comment: thank you! these are what I need and you made it looks so simple.

Comment: if my answer helped you please vote for it if possible.

Comment: not sure why i cant upvote it but I've already marked it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

like this will do :)

```
$collect = $collection->map(function ($item) {
    return collect($item)->values();
});
return $collect->values()->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below.

```
$collect = $collection->map(function ($row) {
     return array_values($row);
});

dd($collect->values()->all());
```

Comment: sorry would like to ask, is that possible if i'd like to get "header 1", "header 2"? :)

Comment: Yes, if you want keys only then you can use array_keys($row)